# Shadow of Holdout object visible in render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, .exr

I've got my Grass collection on Holdout but its Shadow or Ambient Occlusion (highlighted in the image below) is still visible for some reason. This appears in every instance where it is on Holdout. Is there something I missed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plants use transparent textures, and at some point the rays reach their limit of transparent bounces. At this point transparent surfaces are being treated as opaque, leaving solid back in the areas not already covered by holdout shader.

[image: Limits of transparency]

You can solve this issue by increasing the bounces in the render settings under "Light paths" -> "Max bounces" -> "Transparent"

Comment: Thank you! This solution works,